# Convert JS RegExp object into a Pattern object in Java

Tags: javascript, java, regex

So I have these Regex Objs in JS

```
const itemModelRegEx = new RegExp
(/^(item1|item2|item3|item4)(-)(\d{4}((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))(?:.*)/, 'i',);

const dateRegex = new RegExp(/(20\d{2})([0-1]\d)([0-3]\d)/i);
```

currently I am trying to convert them to Java as such:

```
String regexOne = "^(item1|item2|item3|item4)(-)(\d{4}((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))(?:.*)"
Pattern itemModelRegEx = Pattern.compile(regexOne);

Pattern dateRegex = Pattern.compile("(20\d{2})([0-1]\d)([0-3]\d)");
```

However, this doesn't seem to be correct. What would a proper conversion here look like? Would the same wildcards apply? I removed the "/" from start and end but should the "\" in the pattern be set-up differently?

Comment: Try double escaping the backslashes

Comment: Pattern.compile("(20\\d{2})([0-1]\\d)([0-3]\\d)") like this?

Comment: Yes, did you try it out? You can write `[0-1]` as `[01]`

Comment: I don't know yet there's multiple other patterns will update once I have tested properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `\` or `"` in the regex needs to be escaped for the Java string literal.

```
final Pattern itemModelRegEx = Pattern.compile(
        "^(item1|item2|item3|item4)(-)(\\d{4}((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))(?:.*)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Pattern dateRegex = Pattern.compile(
        "(20\\d{2})([0-1]\\d)([0-3]\\d)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

The `i` flag is the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag, and can be specified separately as done in the JS code and in the Java code above. It can also be embedded in the regex itself as `(?i)`, though specifying it for the second pattern doesn't make sense, given that it only matches digits:

```
final Pattern itemModelRegEx = Pattern.compile(
        "(?i)^(item1|item2|item3|item4)(-)(\\d{4}((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))(?:.*)");
final Pattern dateRegex = Pattern.compile(
        "(20\\d{2})([0-1]\\d)([0-3]\\d)");
```